# Remove alternative paths of Openjdk

Tags: java, openjdk

I want to remove 0 and 1(in Selection Column) and keep only 2. How can i do it?

[image]

Comment: 0 and 1 are the same, look at the right column, one is auto mode the other is manual mode.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

should do the job